# Code First Database Creation in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ef-code-first

I know I'm probably being a complete numpty and missing something obvious but I am trying to create a code first database in visual studio 2015.  Now the tables do create BUT they create in the Master database.  Not quite what I am after.

Here is the connection string :-

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="Winstok" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" />
```

(it does have a <\connectionStrings> on the end but for some odd reason that hasnt shown up!)

And here is the initialization in the context :-

```
public DataContext() : base("WinStok")
    {

        Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DataContext>());
    }
```

If anyone could shed some light on what im doing wrong I would be very grateful

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing

```
Initial Catalog=<your database>
```

in the connection string

Comment: Thanks Jurion - told you I'd probably missed something obvious.